# KeystoneJS: add custom dynamic field to generated Admin UI

Tags: javascript, node.js, keystonejs

I use KeystoneJS as Node.js CMS

Is it possible to add **custom dynamic field** to generated Admin UI?

In particular to add custom dynamic link to foreign host to the generated page:

For example I have a model and would like to add `custom_link` to see it in generated UI:

```
Message.add({
  uId: { type: String, initial: true, required: true },
  title: { type: String, initial: true, required: true },
  custom_link: { type: Types.Url, default: 'some_host_name/' + dynamic_unique_name, required: true }
})

Message.defaultColumns = 'runId, stat, custom_link'
Message.register()
```

In that way, generated custom link will be not dynamic constant.

is there a correct way to make it dynamic?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of your use case, but there's no way to add custom fields to Keystone. You could attach a field directly to the Mongo model, but it won't show up in the Admin Panel if you do.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to achieve that is to make pre/post hook using mongoose Scheme to update your custom dynamic field.

For example look here [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48075054/6709144)
or [Mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)